# Exportar DATOS de PhpMyAdmin NO estructura

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

nuevamente con un consulta. Esta ves mi duda es ¿Como exportar los **DATOS** de **PhpMyAdmin** No requiero respaldar su estructura, o sea las tablas y columnas solamente, tambien los datos, claro, si esto es posible. Si no lo es, quizas sea posible ver la consulta completa con la que se creó la tabla o bd junto con su respectiva inserción de datos. Mi caso es que tengo una BD ya realizada pero requiero moverla completamente a otro lado, es algo extensa en realidad, y no quisiera tener que insertar los datos nuevamente. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes recorrer los datos y generar los inserts a tu nueva base. O usar un producto que lo haga automaticamente.

Comment: No comprendo porque no se agrega al comienzo del texto la oracion: "Buenas comunidad". Si es alguna regla de la comunidad por lo menos debería dar una alerta o algo así.

Comment: puede que consultas internas lo hagan(mysqldump) pero debes ejecutarlos en orden los registros porque sino no , te daria error de FK que no existe

Comment: Mira [esta publicacion en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3149/los-saludos-en-castellano-ya-se-eliminan-autom%c3%a1ticamente-de-los-encabezados-de-l) los saludos se eliminan automaticamente, ya que en esta comunidad no son necesarios.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de varias formas. La más rápida sería hacerlo desde la terminal. En dos sencillos pasos: (1). Creas la nueva base de datos: `CREATE DATABASE nuevabd;` y luego (2). Vuelcas todo el contenido de la antigua BD en la nueva: `mysqldump -u usuario -p viejabd | mysql -u backup -pPassword nuevabd;` Tendrás que cambiar los valores `usuario`, `viejabd` y `nuevabd` por tus nombres reales.

Comment: @A.Cedano Esto se hace a travez de la terminal normal de Windows??

Comment: Yo uso `Terminal` de Mac OS. En Windows supongo que será lo mismo,  o sea, desde la línea de comandos que es como se solía llamar en Windows, si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Correcto, ha resultado algo tardío porque la BD es algo extensa pero ha dado el resultado requerido. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando vayas a hacer operaciones *delicadas* sobre la base de datos, sea por la naturaleza de dichas operaciones, sea porque requieren más tiempo, es mejor que lo hagas desde la consola o línea de comandos.

La diferencia de tiempo es considerable y tendrás menos riesgo de que la operación falle o se quede bloqueada a medio camino.

Hacer duplicado de una base de datos mediante la consola es relativamente fácil.

1. Creas la nueva base de datos

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE nuevabd;
   ```
2. Usas `mysqldump` para exportar todo el contenido de la base de datos antigua a un archivo
3. Ahora haces una importación del archivo creado en el paso 2 a la nueva base de datos

Veamos cómo serían los comandos. Supongamos que:

1. el usuario es `root` (puede ser cualquier otro con privilegios para crear bases de datos)
2. la base de datos que existe se llama `viejabd`
3. la base de datos nueva se llama `nuevabd`

**Paso 1: Crear `nuevabd`**:

Entramos con nuestro usuario:

```
>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: **********  -- aquí debes poner la password del usuario
```

Creamos la nueva base de datos:

```
> CREATE DATABASE nuevabd;
```

Puedes verificar si se ha creado:

```
> SHOW DATABASES
```

**Paso 2: Exportamos la base de datos vieja en un archivo `.sql`**

Suponemos que el archivo se guardará en el directorio `c:\bd`

```
>mysqldump -u root -p viejabd > c:\bd\viejabd.sql
Enter password: **********
```

Lo que hace este comando es pedir ingreso a la bd mediante el usuario `root`y exportar el contenido de `viejabd` en un archivo llamado `viejabd.sql` que se encontrará en la ruta indicada. El símbolo `>` significa *exportar*.

**Paso 3: Importamos el archivo creado en el paso 2 a la nueva base de datos**

```
>mysql -u root -p nuevabd < c:\bd\viejabd.sql
Enter password: **********
```

Aquí el operador `<` significa *importar*.

Luego puedes verificar que todo salió como esperando

```
> SHOW TABLES FROM nuevabd;
```

Te mostrará una lista de tablas de la nueva base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

para obtener los datos insertados de una tabla usa la opción de exportar, lo que debes hacer es en PhpMyAdmin busca tu base de datos y entra a la tabla donde necesites obtener sus datos, ejemplo yo necesito los registros de la tabla "tbl_estados" que se encuentra en la base de datos sakila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez que estés en la pestaña exportar le das click al botón continuar y te va a descargar un archivo nombre_de_tu_tabla.sql lo abres con tu editor de código y buscas el insert de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y listo puedes usar ese insert en tu nueva tabla, siempre y cuanto sea la misma esctructura

Comment: Me lanza el siguiente error export.php:Missing parameter: whatDocumentación
export.php: Missing parameter: export_typeDocumentación

Comment: Ok me dejó de mostrar el error pero cuando me genera el archivo .sql, al abrirlo, la seccion donde deberían ir los datos aparece lo siguiente:
-- Base de datos: `tienda`
--

--
-- VIEW  `productos`
-- Datos: Ninguna
--

Comment: que te aparece al principio del archivo, ¿algo como esto?
 http://prntscr.com/ikznei  ¿cuantos registros tienes en la tabla?